# Capybara Webkit not acknowledging @media query for min-width in CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

In my CSS for my application navbar, I hide the desktop version at lower resolutions and only display the mobile element. Beyond a certain breakpoint, I switch it to only display the desktop version -

```
.container {
  .nav-menu.desktop { display: none; }
  .nav-menu.mobile {
    // Mobile CSS
  }

  @media (min-width: 690px) {
    .nav-menu.mobile { display: none; }
    .nav-menu.desktop {
      // Desktop CSS
    }
  }
}
```

To test this, my (simplified) specs look something like

```
context "mobile", :mobile do
  before(:each) do
    # Resize window to mobile
    Capybara.current_session.windows[0].resize_to(400, 730)
  end

  it "user can click a link in the navbar" do
    visit root_path
    click_link("some mobile link")
    expect(page).to have_current_path(home_index_path)
  end
end

context "desktop" do
  before(:each) do
    # Resize window to desktop
    Capybara.current_session.windows[0].resize_to(1440, 800)
  end

  it "user can click a link in the navbar" do
    visit root_path
    click_link("some desktop link")
    expect(page).to have_current_path(home_index_path)
  end
end
```

My desktop specs are failing because it can't find the `nav-menu.desktop` element that's supposed to show up at that resolution.

I think the issue is that in the CSS it's not acknowledging the media query for the `min-width` and so it's still applying the `display: none` rule for the desktop element. I can confirm this buy commenting that out and then the test passes fine, and also visually by using `save_and_open_screenshot`

It also explains why there's no issue with the mobile specs, since the CSS by default is written for the mobile resolution.

Is there a way to force Capybara Webkit to acknowledge the media query rule?

Using `capybara-webkit (1.11.1)` and `capybara (2.7.1)`

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `windows[0]` is the actual current window?  If you've opened other windows the return order of `#windows` is not guaranteed - Try `Capybara.current_session.current_window.resize_to ...`  instead.  Also, what version of Qt was your capybara-webkit built with?

Comment: Hey Tom - thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately using `current_window` didn't work either. (The application never opens multiple windows anyway). The current version of `capybara-webkit` is using Qt `v4.8.7`

Comment: Qt 4.8 is really outdated will produce all sorts of missing functionality headaches - Rebuild capybara-webkit with the latest Qt 5.5.x release (I don't believe 5.6.x is supported without manually building a bunch of stuff, if at all) - Media queries works fine for me when built with 5.5.1 - https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit - Also I'm assuming it works correctly for you in dev mode ( you do have a `display: block` or something in the Desktop css section to override the default display: none )

Comment: Just installed Qt `v5.5.1`, still no luck :( You're assumption is correct though, it definitely works in dev mode. The desktop content correctly displays at widths greater than `690px`, and is hidden for widths less than that.

Comment: @user2490003 Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into something very similar.

Comment: @OddityOverseer - I did not, sorry :(